# Grails - not-null property references a null or transient value error only with concurrent users

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

a web application that we have been developing in Grails has recently moved into the stress testing phase, and now we are encountering this issue that seems to only be happening when multiple users (different user accounts) perform the same actions at the same time.  These actions are transactional but none of them are executed on the same object (new objects are being created). The exception that we have been getting is:

> Class: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException
>   Message: not-null property references a null or transient value: xxx.xxx.xxx.domains.PathSections._PathViews_sectionsBackref

This is generally what the exception looks like, with some variations to the involved domain classes. To make it even worse, when this error occurs, every other transactional action that involves a list will result in the same error (different domain classes), whether concurrently done or not.  The server then needs to be restarted in order to temporarily fix it.  Here are some snippets of the relevant domain classes:

```
class PathViews extends View{

static constraints = {
    molreports(nullable:true)
    molorders(nullable:true)
    otherreports(nullable: true)
    sections(nullable:true)
    addendum(nullable:true)
    images(nullable:true)
    edits(nullable:true)
}

List sections
List otherreports
List molreports
List molorders
List images
PathEdits edits
PathSections addendum
int headings
String accid

static auditable = true

static hasMany = [sections: PathSections, otherreports: PathSections, molorders:MolecularOrder, molreports: MolecularReport, images: PathLocalImage]

static mappedBy = [sections: 'pathviews', otherreports: 'reports']


class PathSections extends Sections {

static constraints = {
    pathviews(nullable:true)
    reports(nullable:true)
}


static auditable = true

static belongsTo =  [pathviews: PathViews, reports: PathViews]
```

}

A temporary fix that I thought was working at first was to make most of the transactional service methods synchronized.  This seems to have just made the error more random and less reproducible. I have also double checked other things such as making sure the child objects of a hasMany relationship are not explicitly saved before being added to a parent and using domainClass.lock(id) instead of domainClass.get(id).  This issue does not occur at all when it's just one user using the application.

Versions used:

> Grails: 2.3.7
>   Hibernate: 3.6.10.10

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm close to pulling out whatever's left of my hair right now, and please let me know if anymore information is needed.

Thanks!
Shawn.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is upgrade to the latest version within the same minor version - 2.3.11. It's unlikely to help, but you might get lucky.

Collections are tricky, since they're considered a property of the owning domain class, but are represented as multiple database records. So you have interesting effects like not being able to properly lock an updating instance; given "Author has many Books", if you explicitly lock an author instance the resulting SQL is something like `select ... from author for update where id=?`. But you can't lock the books, and if you could and the collection were much larger, would you want to lock a million collection instances? So you inevitably get concurrency problems with many-to-many where child items are shared between top-level instances, and even with yourself when doing Ajax requests that overlap with synchronous requests.

And that's just data correctness - the potential performance costs of using collections for persistence in GORM are pretty high. [This talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) that I did 4 years ago is as relevent now as it was then, and it demonstrates the performance issues with 1-many and many-many, and shows code that doesn't use collections and isn't affected by any of these issues. You do have to do a little more work, but I think it's a small price to pay.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Burt.  Unfortunately, the update didnt seem to help much and it's a bit late in development to completely reimplement all the collections.  It will be definitely something to look at though for the next revision.  Do you have suggestions on how we may be able to catch the exception early enough so we can at least avoid having to restart the server?

Comment: No need to do everyone at once - you can convert 1 collection at a time. This should only affect a few collections. For 1-many if your mapping generates a foreign key (vs a join table) then the conversion is fairly minor; create a Book not via `author.addToBooks()` but with explicit set of `author`, e.g. `new Book(title: '...', author: author).save()`. For read-only inverse access it's easy to replace the collection with a query, e.g. `def books = Book.findAllByAuthor(this)`. No DB changes required.

Comment: If ordering of the items is needed, how would that be addressed in this implementation? Would I somehow have to manually set the idx fields that already exist in the database?

Comment: Yes, that would be a bit of work. If you look at the Hibernate approach, they delete everything from the join table and re-insert to ensure all idx values are correct. Hopefully with domain knowledge you could do something smarter :) This is one gap between the two approaches that I haven't though much about; typically insertion order is less important than the value of a property that can be used for sorting (e.g. last-updated) - how would you do this if you weren't using Hibernate?